# Modular arithmetic $7^{60} \pmod{77}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> How do you solve $7^{60} \pmod{77}$?

For $5^{60} \pmod{77}$, it's equal to $1$ because I think the $\gcd(5,77) = 1$ and using the FLT we can find that $5^{(7-1)(11-1)} = 1 \pmod{7*11}$. But how do you get $56$ from $7^{60} \pmod{77}$?

Comment: CRT with $7^{60}\pmod{11}$ and $7^{60}\equiv 0\pmod{7}$

Comment: Note:  $7^{10}\equiv1\bmod11$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3932977/remainder-of-division-when-p-is-not-prime/3932990#3932990  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3789602/finding-the-last-2-digits-of-6513/3789621#3789621

Comment: $7^{60}\!\bmod 77 = 7 (\overbrace{7^{60}\!/7 \bmod 11}^{\textstyle \color{#c00}{1/7}\  {\rm by} \  7^{10}\!\equiv 1\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}) =  7(\color{#c00}8)\  $ by $\bmod 11\!:\ \color{#c00}{\dfrac{1}7} \equiv\dfrac{12}{-4} \equiv -3 \equiv\color{#c00}8\ $ as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3933049/242). We have hundreds of questions on this topic. Please search first.

Answer (score 1):

First, $7^{60}\equiv 0\pmod{7}$. Then:

$$7^{60}\equiv \big(7^{10}\big)^{6}\equiv \big(7^{\phi(11)}\big)^{6}\equiv 1^{6}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$$

Then, $7^{60}\equiv 0\pmod{7}$ and $7^{60}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$, so $7^{60}$ is equivalent to a unique value $\pmod{77}$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. And since $56\equiv 0\pmod{7}, 1\pmod{11}$, we must have $\boxed{7^{60}\equiv 56\pmod{77}.}$